# How to Implementing iOS 13 Mail App like Two-Finger Pan Gesture Selection When Swipe Action is Visible?

Tags: ios, uitableview

This is my app with one bookmark action implemented with `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt`.

**What I need is to make the app editable through two-finger pan gesture when this bookmark action is visible, same as iOS 13's Mail App.**

[image: App Demo]

As far as I know, the delegate method `tableView(_:shouldBeginMultipleSelectionInteractionAt:)` is needed to acheive such interaction. `didBeginMultipleSelectionInteractionAt` may have some use.

**But strangely, `shouldBeginMultipleSelectionInteractionAt` is not fired when swipe action is visible**. And swipe action also set `tableView.isEditing` to `true`. So when the bookmark action is visible, the tableView's `isEditing` is `true`.

Based on my testing on iOS 13, while `didBeginMultipleSelectionInteractionAt` is fired when swipe action is visible, it's also fired everytime a row is selected or deselected. So I think it's hard to toggle `editting mode` here.

I think there are should be some easy ways to do it as Mail App already have this interaction. What am I missing here?

[image: Mail App Action Demo]

Comment: It's unclear what the question is. You know about `shouldBeginMultipleSelectionInteractionAt` so what else is there to know?

Comment: @matt I changed my question a little. Basically it's that I want to select the row with two finger pan gesture when swipe action is visible. I can get it work when swipe action is invisible.

Comment: Probably impossible.